# Find the UMVUE of $P\{{X_i < Y_i\}}$ for $X_i,..X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y_i,..Y_n \sim N(\nu, \sigma^2)$

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator, umvue

I have to find the UMVUE of $P\{{X_i < Y_i\}}$ for $X_i,..X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y_i,..Y_n \sim N(v, \sigma^2$).

I know that I have to find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ which I have here as: $f(x,y) = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-4}exp(1/2\sigma^2 ( (x_i +y_i) exp(-(\mu + v))$. The $T(x)$ = $(x_i +y_i)$ is therefore complete and sufficient.

So by Rao-Blackwell
$E_{\theta}[h(T)] = P\{{X_i < Y_i\}}$

$\int_{-\infty}^{y} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t)(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-4}exp(1/2\sigma^2 ( (x_i +y_i) exp(-(\mu + v))dy dx/{ P(t=x_i +y_i)} = P\{{X_i - Y_i < 0\}} $

How can I reduce this equation?

Comment: $X_i<Y_i$ is equivalent to $X_i-Y_i<0$, and that's easier to work with

Comment: Check your title; it doesn't seem to match your body text. Please fix

Comment: Check also your pdf: as given it is not a density..

Comment: $\mu,\nu,\sigma$ all are unknown?